# MySQL INNER JOIN IN not getting right result

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in my php and it seems to be fetching the wrong data set from my db.

```
$querystring = " 

SELECT a.*, 
       b.itemcolour, 
       b.itemcolourname 
FROM   itemorders AS a 
       INNER JOIN catalogueitemscolour AS b 
               ON a.colourid = b.colourid 
WHERE  a.colourid IN(SELECT colourid 
                     FROM   itemorders 
                     WHERE  orderid = 61) 

";
```

Here is a picture of my results

[image: sample]

Can I know why it's not selecting the specific orderID of 61?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is selecting all rows where `a.colourID` matches anything `colourID` that has an `orderID` of 61.  If you want to restrict the results ONLY to show where `orderID` is 61, then explicitly add this to your main `WHERE` clause

Comment: You are selecting all products with colourID same as in orderId=61

Comment: because you are doing a where clause on the colorID with a subquery that have orderID at `61` but row with orderID at `61` might have the color as other orderID

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
SELECT a.*, b.itemColour,b.itemColourName FROM itemorders 
AS a INNER JOIN CatalogueItemsColour AS b ON a.colourID = b.colourID WHERE 
a.orderID = 61
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not putting condition on `orderID`, rather putting it on `colorID`. What you actually want is this condition: `WHERE a.orderID = 61`.